# Ionic Radio Button long response time on iPad Air

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to create an application for showing a questionnaire but whenever I press a radio button, the response is delayed by at least a few seconds. This problem however only appears whenever I'm testing the application on an iPad Air or when I set the CPU throttling on 6x slowdown in Google Dev Tools. The computer I'm working on has a intel i5-760 with 2.8 GHz. I've also found that reducing the amount of radio buttons increases the performance aswell. At this moment, I have 30-50 questions with 3 radio buttons each on a single page so around 90-150 radio buttons so it might be because of the sheer amount of buttons I have on a page. I am not sure about this though.

The code below shows the HTML I use for showing the answers:

```
<div *ngFor="let question of Questions" radio-group formControlName="{{'question' + question.Id}}" class="question-container" [ngClass]="{'custom-highlight': question.Highlight}">
  <div text-left class="question">
    <h3>{{question.QuestionText}}</h3>
  </div>
  <div text-wrap class="answer-container">
    <ion-list mode="md" no-lines>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let answer of question.Answers">
        <div class="answer">
          <ion-item no-padding mode="md" class="no-background">
            <ion-label mode="md" [innerHTML]="answer.Label | translate"></ion-label>
            <ion-radio mode="md" id="answer{{answer.Id}}" item-start value="{{answer.Label}}" checked="{{questionnaireForm.get('answer' + answer.Id).value ? questionnaireForm.get('answer' + answer.Id).value : false}}" (click)="clicked(answer)"></ion-radio>
          </ion-item>
          <div *ngIf="questionnaireForm.get('answer' + answer.Id).errors" class="text-danger">
            <small text-left>{{getErrorMessageForAnswer(questionnaireForm.get('answer' + answer.Id).errors)}}</small>
          </div>
        <small text-left *ngIf="answer.Hint" class="form-text text-muted" [innerHTML]="answer.Hint"></small>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-list>
</div>
```

I've tried timing my answers by logging Date.now() at the start of the method and at the end of the method. Since this method is recursive, I put a `console.log(Date.now())` at the end of the recursive method. This method always finished in ~100ms-150ms. I'm not sure if this is the right way to time my method so I'm a bit skeptical and my code might actually be trash.

I've also checked the profiler of Google Dev Tools and it showed me this [Google Dev Tools Profiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noztY.png). I have no clue what this means or which events are called since I've tried removing the click event from the radio button and it still called the same events.

Please help, and if you do, thank you.

Comment: See if your click action is causing the entire thing to be re-rendered because of the model changing. Log out your renders.

Comment: @Diodeus-JamesMacFarlane Sadly, it does not. I do have slides though and they do re-render when I switch from one to the other. I thought the problem might be because of the amount of radio-groups but nothing conclusive so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've found, the reason why Radio buttons respond so late on low-end mobiles is because of the amount of elements I'm trying to load. Sometimes I render 52 questions with 3 options each. This slowed down the application. To fix this, I implemented the ngx-virtual-scroller since the Ionic Virtual Scroll for some reason didn't want to load the items.
This probably has something to do with the application structure of the company. But that's a problem for another day.